# kohana custom routes

Tags: php, routes, kohana

I am having some trouble coming up with the routes for the following scenario...

I have a module controller in say...

/modules/mymodule/classes/controller/mymodule.php (class Controller_Mymodule)
and the url being

/mymodule/

and then I want to have the admin controller
/modules/mymodule/classes/controller/admin/mymodule.php (class Controller_Admin_Mymodule)

but the url would be

/admin/mymodule/

I am trying this route below but I am getting the error: Unable to find a route to match the URI: admin

```
 Route::set('admin', 'admin/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))')
  ->defaults(array(
      'directory'  => 'admin',
      'controller' => 'pages',
      'action'     => 'index',
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to find a route to match the
>   URI: admin

Does it mean that `admin/mymodule` works? Anyway, `admin` will failed because your route has required `controller` param. Here is the same route with optional `controller` segment:

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
  ->defaults(array(
      'directory'  => 'admin',
      'controller' => 'pages',
      'action'     => 'index',
  ));
```

PS. You can skip `action` param because 'index' is a default value.